# Suppressing load of sfdx.js in VS Code in debug mode

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

When you develop a plugin for the SFDX CLI and use the `--dev-suspend` flag at the end of your command in a VS Code terminal, the first thing that is loaded is a new document that contains the core **sfdx.js** file.

Is there any means of suppressing the visual document load within VS Code in this case since it is connecting to a remote debugger?

My current launch config in my .vscode folder for a project:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Remote",
      "address": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 9229,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Run All Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": ["--inspect", "--no-timeouts", "--colors", "test/**/*.test.ts"],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "SFDX_ENV": "development"
      },
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "preLaunchTask": "Compile"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Run Current Test",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": ["--inspect", "--no-timeouts", "--colors", "${file}"],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "SFDX_ENV": "development"
      },
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "preLaunchTask": "Compile"
    }
  ]
}
```